# 502 Bad Gateway when deploying and running Spring Maven app within Openshift

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, openshift

Generic Hello world Spring Maven application using Java 17

Dockerfile

```
from amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk as application-builder
#copy project
RUN mkdir /project
COPY . /project
RUN apk add maven
#get project and package it up
WORKDIR /project
RUN mvn clean package

from amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk as application-runner
COPY --from=application-builder /project/target/colosseo-api-toolbelt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /project/target/colosseo-api-toolbelt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java","-jar","/project/target/colosseo-api-toolbelt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Link to the public repo to assist in determining issues
https://github.com/Epooch/spring-hello-world-maven.git

I can build the docker image locally and run it successfully.

When deploying to openshift

```
docker build -t spring-hello-world-maven .

oc project $OC_PROJECT
OC_PATCH_STATUS=$(oc patch deploymentconfig spring-hello-world-maven -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"name\":\"spring-hello-world-maven\",\"image\": \"spring-hello-world-maven\"}]}}}}")
echo $OC_PATCH_STATUS
if [[ "$OC_PATCH_STATUS" == *"not patched" ]]; then
 oc rollout latest dc/$SELECTOR
 oc rollout status dc/$SELECTOR
fi
oc logout
```

When we view the logs of the running pod it is showing the successfully deployed spring application. However when navigating to the URL it is returning "502 Bad Gateway".

I do not have a lot of experience with Openshift so trying to understand were things may have slipped in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Found out there was an issue with the service configuration. It was not linked to the pod. The deployment config needed to be referenced in the service yml.